# Ruby Regexp: difference between new and union with a single regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I have simplified the examples. Say I have a string containing the code for a regex. I would like the regex to match a literal dot and thus I want it to be:

```
\.
```

So I create the following Ruby string:

```
"\\."
```

However when I use it with Regexp.union to create my regex, I get this:

```
irb(main):017:0> Regexp.union("\\.")
=> /\\\./
```

That will match a slash followed by a dot, not just a single dot. Compare the previous result to this:

```
irb(main):018:0> Regexp.new("\\.")
=> /\./
```

which gives the Regexp I want but without the needed union.

Could you explain why Ruby acts like that and how to make the correct union of regexes ? The context of utilization is that of importing JSON strings describing regexes and union-ing them in Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a string to `Regexp.union` is designed to match that string literally. There is no need to escape it, `Regexp.escape` is already called internally.

```
Regexp.union(".")
#=> /\./
```

If you want to pass regular expressions to `Regexp.union`, don't use strings:

```
Regexp.union(Regexp.new("\\."))
#=> /\./
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\.` is where you went wrong I think, if you want to match a `.` you should just use the first one `\.` Now you have a `\` and `\.` and the first one is escaped.

To be safe just use the standard regex provided by Ruby which would be `Regexp.new /\./` in your case

If you want to use union just use `Regexp.union "."` which should return `/\./`

From the ruby regex class:

```
Regexp.union("a+b*c")                #=> /a\+b\*c/
```