# Regexp union in ruby escapes my original regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I've got multiple regexes and I want to use Regexp.union to combine them in one big regex so I have this regex to show as an example:

```
^image\d*$
```

So I try this :

```
regex = %w(^image\d*$)
=> ["^image\\d*$"]
re = Regexp.union(regex)
=> /\^image\\d\*\$/
```

And it escapes my regex to `/\^image\\d\*\$/` so when I try the basic case it doesn't match :

```
"image0".match(re)
 => nil
```

How can I get arround this?

Comment: That's the expected behavior: [Ruby Regexp: difference between new and union with a single regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784717/ruby-regexp-difference-between-new-and-union-with-a-single-regexp)

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because while the other question does answer this question - others with this problem are more likely to google for the above problem than to ask how regex-unon works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass [`Regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) object. `%w(...)` is string literal. Use `%r(...)` or `/.../` for regular expression literal.

```
regex = %r(^image\d*$)
# => /^image\d*$/
Regexp.union(regex)
# => /^image\d*$/
```

---

```
array_of_regexs = [/a/, /b/, /c/]
# => [/a/, /b/, /c/]
Regexp.union(array_of_regexs)
# => /(?-mix:a)|(?-mix:b)|(?-mix:c)/
```

Comment: how can I use array of regexes?